# How can i split a binary in erlang

Tags: erlang, binary

What I want is, I think, relatively simple:

```
> Bin = <<"Hello.world.howdy?">>.
> split(Bin, ".").
[<<"Hello">>, <<"world">>, <<"howdy?">>]
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no current OTP function that is the equivalent of `lists:split/2` that works on a binary string. Until [EEP-9](http://www.erlang.org/eeps/eep-0009.html) is made public, you might write a binary split function like:

```
split(Binary, Chars) ->
    split(Binary, Chars, 0, 0, []).

split(Bin, Chars, Idx, LastSplit, Acc)
  when is_integer(Idx), is_integer(LastSplit) ->
    Len = (Idx - LastSplit),
    case Bin of
        <<_:LastSplit/binary,
         This:Len/binary,
         Char,
         _/binary>> ->
            case lists:member(Char, Chars) of
                false ->
                    split(Bin, Chars, Idx+1, LastSplit, Acc);
                true ->
                    split(Bin, Chars, Idx+1, Idx+1, [This | Acc])
            end;
        <<_:LastSplit/binary,
         This:Len/binary>> ->
            lists:reverse([This | Acc]);
        _ ->
            lists:reverse(Acc)
    end.
```

Answer (score 20):

```
binary:split(Bin,<<".">>).
```

Comment: This only splits the first item, so the return value would be [<<Hello>>,<<World.Howdy?>>].  The solution is to the pass the global option: binary:split(Bin,<<".">>, [global]).

Answer (score 10):

The module [binary](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/binary.html) from [EEP31](http://www.erlang.org/eeps/eep-0031.html) (and [EEP9](http://www.erlang.org/eeps/eep-0009.html)) was added in [Erts-5.8](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/notes.html#id129226) (see OTP-8217):

```
1> Bin = <<"Hello.world.howdy?">>.
<<"Hello.world.howdy?">>
2> binary:split(Bin, <<".">>, [global]).
[<<"Hello">>,<<"world">>,<<"howdy?">>]
```

Answer (score 5):

There is about 15% faster version of binary split working in R12B:

```
split2(Bin, Chars) ->
    split2(Chars, Bin, 0, []).

split2(Chars, Bin, Idx, Acc) ->
    case Bin of
        <<This:Idx/binary, Char, Tail/binary>> ->
            case lists:member(Char, Chars) of
                false ->
                    split2(Chars, Bin, Idx+1, Acc);
                true ->
                    split2(Chars, Tail, 0, [This|Acc])
            end;
        <<This:Idx/binary>> ->
            lists:reverse(Acc, [This])
    end.
```

If you are using R11B or older use archaelus [version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428124/how-can-i-split-a-binary-in-erlang#428852) instead.

The above code is faster on std. BEAM bytecode only, not in HiPE, there are both almost same.

**EDIT**: Note this code obsoleted by new module [binary](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/binary.html) since R14B. Use `binary:split(Bin, <<".">>, [global]).` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

```
re:split(<<"Hello.world.howdy?">>, "\\.").
```