# Erlang howto make a list from this binary <<"a,b,c">>

Tags: string, list, binary, erlang

I have a binary `<<"a,b,c">>` and I would like to extract the information from this binary.

So I would like to have something like `A=a, B=b` and so on. 
I need a general approach on this because the binary string always changes.

So it could be `<<"aaa","bbb","ccc">>`...

I tried to generate a list

```
erlang:binary_to_list(<<"a","b","c">>)
```

but I get string as a result.

```
"abc"
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You did use the right method.

> [binary_to_list(Binary) -> [char()]](http://erldocs.com/R14B/erts/erlang.html?i=3&search=binary_to#binary_to_list/1)
>
> Returns a list of integers which correspond to the bytes of Binary.

There is no string type in Erlang: http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id63119. The console just displays the lists in string representation as a courtesy, if all elements are in printable ASCII range.

You should read Erlang's ["Bit Syntax Expressions"](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#bit_syntax) documentation to understand how to work on binaries.

**Do not convert the whole binary into a list if you don't need it in list representation!**

To extract the first three bytes you could use

```
<<A, B, C, Rest/binary>> = <<"aaa","bbb","ccc">>.
```

If you want to iterate over the binary data, you can use binary comprehension.

```
<< <<(F(X))>> || <<X>> <= <<"aaa","bbb","ccc">> >>.
```

Pattern matching is possible, too:

```
test(<<A, Tail/binary>>, Accu) -> test(Tail, Accu+A);
test(_, Accu) -> Accu.

882 = test(<<"aaa","bbb","ccc">>, 0).
```

Even for reading one UTF-8 character at once. So to [convert a binary UTF-8 string](http://erldocs.com/R14B/stdlib/unicode.html?i=3&search=unicode%3a#characters_to_binary/3) into Erlang's "list of codepoints" format, you could use:

```
test(<<A/utf8, Tail/binary>>, Accu) -> test(Tail, [A|Accu]);
test(_, Accu) -> lists:reverse(Accu).

[97,97,97,600,99,99,99] = test(<<"aaa", 16#0258/utf8, "ccc">>, "").
```

(Note that `` `<<"aaa","bbb","ccc">> = <<"aaabbbccc">> ``. Don't actually use the last code snipped but the linked method.)

Comment: Thank you for your time, the problem is i do need a list representation of binary. I would like to build something like this structure [{user, andreas},{adress,germany}] from a binary. I never know how many bytes id have to extract do get the first Term {user,adreas}. I thought i could use a binary <<user,andreas,adress,germany>> and convert this binary to a list so i could get the information from a binary.

Comment: Do you want to split the binary data at a given token? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428124/how-can-i-split-a-binary-in-erlang

Comment: I tried the solution at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428124/how-can-i-split-a-binary-in-erlang) and it works but it is not an elegant way to solve my problem because i would have to forbid the usage of a special token in my application.

Comment: How else would you separate the fields in `<<user,andreas,address,germany>>`? The commas don't actually show up in the binaries. But I'd say 0 is a rather safe character for  …delimiting text data …

Comment: Ok what i did is `binary:split(<<"{aaa,aa0a}\0{bbb,ccc}">>,[<<"\0">>],[global]).` as a result i get `[<<"{aaa,aa0a}">>,<<"{bbb,ccc}">>]`

Comment: I'd rather say you should put an integer mark show many bytes of data will follow: `<<(byte_size(Name)):16/unsigned-integer-little>>`. Then you can split your data using [split_binary](http://erldocs.com/R14B/erts/erlang.html?i=0&search=split#split_binary/2) at the denoted position.

Comment: it is actually not a bad idea. I´ll try it out later. Thank you.